# Would hibernate crash if there is a column which does not exist as a property of entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

Let's say we have an entity class,

```
Person
-------
- Name
- Surname
```

*We have a table,*

```
---------------

Name | Surname 

----------------
```

*Then without changing the entity class we alter table and add a column to table, (with option `not null false` )*

```
----------------------

Name | Surname | Age 

----------------------
```

My question is without changing any code, change on the db like above would affect hibernate runtime or not?

For example, getting or saving a person object would crash the runtime because of that database change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate ignores not mapped columns. So your `Age` column would not affect anything.

But if this column has not null constraint and doesn't have default value, then hibernate insert queries will fail.